# Docker based development environment for multiple projects

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, development-environment, lamp

I am wondering about the best architecture for a Docker based development environment with a LAMP stack.

**Requirements**

- Working on multiple projects in parallel
- Most projects are using the same LAMP stack (for simplicity let's assume that all projects are sharing the same stack and configuration)
- The host is running Windows + VBox + Docker Toolbox (i.e. Boot2Docker)

**Current architecture**

- One shared development environment running multiple containers (web, db, persistent data..) with vhosts configuration per site
- Using scripts / Jenkins container to setup new project (new DB, vhost configuration..)
- Running custom Samba container to share the data with the Windows machine (IDE is running on Windows)

As always there are pros. and cons., while this is quite easy for maintenance, we are unable to really deploy a specific project with a dedicated docker-compose.yml file, and we are also unable to get all the benefits of "micro services" like replacing PHP / MySQL version for a specific site.

The question is how can we use a per project docker-compose.yml file, but still have multiple projects running simultaneously (since all projects are using port 80).
Will it be better (and is it even possible?) to use random ports per project and run a proxy layer on top of those web containers?

Any other options or common design patterns for this use case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Docker by default assigns random ports if no port it is specified. For mapping I would use: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

You can have something like project1.yml project2.yml .... and to start the containers would be something like:

```
docker-comppse -f project1.yml up
```

However, I'm not sure why would you try to do that. You could use something like Rancher and split my development host into multiple small development environments.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rancher but from their documentation they're mostly talking about production environments.  Why don't you like the first solution you offered?

Comment: Yes but it allows you to do is to have stacks that are made of 1 or more hosts and it is entirely up to you for what you want to use it for (dev, pre-prod, prod). However, you could try as you have mentioned with different docker compose files for different projects and see how it goes